# Reference plugin XML in pom.xml across multiple profiles without copy and paste

Tags: xml, maven

I have a multiple module maven project with three different maven profiles.  In a specific module, the plugin XML is identical for two of the three profiles.  Is there a way to reference this plugin XML definition so I don't need to copy and paste it in two spots?

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <!-- unique plugin code -->
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <!-- identical XML for profile2 and profile3 -->
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile3</id>
        <!-- identical XML for profile2 and profile3 -->
    </profile>
```

I have it working, but I've copied and pasted the same XML for profile2 and profile3.

I can't change the profile names and/or modify the maven command that runs these modules.

Comment: So what aspects do `profile2` and `profile3` differ from each other at? Why not externalize those attributes alone as configurable properties keeping only one of these identical profiles?